# Invoke-Command not finding script, but it's there

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, remote-execution

I'm attempting to run a very simple script on a different server and am getting an ItemNotFoundException. Here's my script:

```
Invoke-Command  -ComputerName myserver -FilePath C:\laurietest\testthis.ps1  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver  -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Output "Directory before copying:"
    Get-ChildItem C:\laurietest\
    Copy-Item -Path C:\laurietest\output.txt -Destination C:\laurietest\output2.txt
      Write-Output "Directory after copying:"
      Get-ChildItem C:\laurietest\
}
```

And here's the output I get when I run the command:
[image]
It lists the contents of the directory and the file testthis.ps1 is definitely there, but the Invoke-Command can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-FilePath` parameter [expects a *local file path*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-1--run-a-script-on-a-server).

If the path refers to a file on the remote machine you'll want to use the `-ScriptBlock` parameter instead:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -ScriptBlock { C:\laurietest\testthis.ps1 }`

Or, if you need to pass a variable path:

```
$remoteScriptFilePath = 'C:\laurietest\testthis.ps1'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver -ScriptBlock { & $using:remoteScriptFilePath }
```